# How does moving the pericenter affect the apocenter?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, satellites

A perfectly circular orbit of a constant height (distance from the center of mass of the orbited planet) around a perfectly spherical planet with smooth surface and no gravitational anomalies will have a certain constant orbital velocity, specific for the given height and planet (specifically, its mass, I presume).

Consider a circular orbit of the constant height $H$ and orbital velocity $V$; and an elliptical orbit $O_e$ with pericenter $H_p$ and apocenter $H_a$. Given that

- the average orbital velocity of $O_e$ is equal to $V$,
- $H > H_p$, and
- $H_p = H - \Delta{H}$

… **how to calculate $H_a$**?

I don't think that $H_a = H + \Delta{H}$ is correct.

Since I'm not a physicist nor a mathematician, I expect that the answer is not too involved. I can do math, but I don't have the knowledge to solve fourth-order partial differential equations.

Comment: I can see that the question looks like a homework assignment, – it is not  In reality, I play an orbital mechanics game on a smartphone, and the game mechanics is too simplistic to allow me to find this behaviour experimentally.